Confusions Regarding Definitions of Dom R and Ran R
I am using Hrbacek & Jech's Intro. to Set Theory. In page 19, for a relation $R$, $\operatorname{dom} R$ and $\operatorname{ran} R$ is defined as follows:

Let $R$ be a binary relation.
(a) The set of all $x$ which are in relation $R$ with some $y$ is called the domain of $R$ and denoted by $\operatorname{dom} R$. So $\operatorname{dom} R = \{x \mid \text{there exists } y\text{ such that }xRy\}$. $\operatorname{dom} R$ is the set of all first coordinates of ordered pairs in $R$.
(b) The set of all $y$ such that, for some $x$, $x$ is in relation $R$ with $y$ is called the range of $R$, denoted by $\operatorname{ran} R$. So $\operatorname{ran} R = \{y \mid \text{there exists } x\text{ such that }xRy\}$. $\operatorname{ran} R$ is the set of all second coordinates of ordered pairs in $R$.

Here I do not understand why the definition should be written as it is. Considering $\operatorname{dom} R$ for example, it feels that "there exists $y$ such that" from the definition is redundant, since we can just gather all $x$ such that $(x, y) \in R$. Why do we need more than the definitions
$\operatorname{dom} R = \{x \mid xRy\}$ and $\operatorname{ran} R = \{y \mid xRy\}$?

Note that ${x|xRy}={a|aRy}$ so $x$ is not free.

If you do that, how would you denote the set ${x\mid \text{ for all $y$ we have } xRy}$? Wouldn't that be ${x\mid xRy}$ since the "for all $y$ we have" is redundant?

In $\operatorname{dom}R = \{x \mid xRy\}$, what is $y$? You haven't specified what $y$ actually is so this definition is meaningless. The definition isn't redunant – the domain really is all $x$ such that there is some $y$ with $xRy$. It's like defining a set $S = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x > z\}$. Well what's $z$?
